# Is it possible to add a delay between observations on the Realtime Database with Firebase Unity SDK?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I set up a ValueChanged observer on a branch on the Firebase Realtime Database. I want to get the value every time it changes but only in the span of 10 seconds. (Let's say, it changes on t = 0, if it changes again at t = 5 I shouldn't get any updates, I should only get them at t= 10 after the delay time of 10 seconds has elapsed).

Is there a way to do this with Firebase observers? I am trying to download the data only when I need it and not constantly when it's changing.